# Show attribute class in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, attributes, propertygrid

I'm working on a project where i have made the following class layout, and i need to display it on a PropertyGrid:

Bar.cs:
This attribute stores information of a Foo class, my code has more application specific properties, but only uses strings, bools or enums

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter)]
class Bar : Attribute
{
    public string Author = "Unknown";
    public string Description = "Unknown";
}
```

Foo.cs:
This is a base class for my application, and has the Bar attribute to expose information about the class, this works fine because this.GetType() returns the type of the instance, not the class its defined in.

```
[Bar(Author="Someone",Description="Base class")]
class Foo
{
    public int MyInt {get;set;}
    [Browsable(true)]
    public Bar MyBar
    {
        return (Bar)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(this.GetType(), Typeof(Bar));
    }
}
```

AnotherClass.cs:
This class inherits from Foo but uses the Bar attribute to expose information about the class

```
[Bar(Author="NotMe",Description="Derived class")]
class AnotherClass : Foo
{
}
```

Now i want to display the Foo class (or derived) on a PropertyGrid, which so far works fine, until i want to display the Bar property, because it only shows the 'TypeId' property. The reason i have the MyBar property in the first place is because i found it an easy way to get the attribute of a class in runtime(in case GetCustomAttribute() return null, the get code will return a default instance of the attribute, not shown here). Do i need to make my own TypeConverter, or am i missing an attribute somewhere?

Thank you for reading my question

Comment: Do you assign `Foo` directly as `PropertyGrid.SelectedObject`? Normally you could use a wrapper (`ICustomTypeDescriptor`) and custom collection of properties (`PropertyDescriptor`) to control what you see and how you see it.

Comment: Yes i do assign it directly and thanks I'll try that

Comment: I found that the Author, Description and variables alike are not properties as i asumed, but they are fields. You have to write a TypeConverter and PropertyDescriptor in order to expose the fields